# How to convert HTML to Javascript escapes in C#

Tags: c#, html, unicode

I have converted a Hindi font to HTML code. Now what I want is to convert this HTML code to unicode escapes...

Hindi:

```
श्रीगंगानगर। हनुमानगढ़ मार्ग पर लालगढ़ जाटान छावनी के नजदीक शनिवार सुबह सड़क से पन्द्रह-...
```

Corresponding HTML:

`&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2306;&#2327;&#2366;&#2344;&#2327;&#2352;&#2404; &#2361;&#2344;&#2369;&#2350;&#2366;&#2344;&#2327;&#2338;&#2364; &#2350;&#2366;&#2352;&#2381;&#2327; &#2346;&#2352; &#2354;&#2366;&#2354;&#2327;&#2338;&#2364; &#2332;&#2366;&#2335;&#2366;&#2344; &#2331;&#2366;&#2357;&#2344;&#2368; &#2325;&#2375; &#2344;&#2332;&#2342;&#2368;&#2325; &#2358;&#2344;&#2367;&#2357;&#2366;&#2352; &#2360;&#2369;&#2348;&#2361; &#2360;&#2337;&#2364;&#2325; &#2360;&#2375; &#2346;&#2344;&#2381;&#2342;&#2381;&#2352;&#2361;-...`

Now I want to convert this HTML code to unicode escapes like:

> \u0936\u094D\u0930\u0940\u0917\u0902\u0917\u093E\u0928\u0917\u0930\u0964 \u0939\u0928\u0941\u092E\u093E\u0928\u0917\u0922\u093C \u092E\u093E\u0930\u094D\u0917 \u092A\u0930

Just like in [this site](http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/). But I want this conversion through C# code, not in Javascript...

Comment: That's a simple decimal-to-hex conversion and string manipulation.

Comment: thanks i will search about it i dont know how to do that lets see if it help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you got multiple answers directly from the raw text, here's a way to do it from your HTML escapes as you asked;

```
string input = "&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2306;&#2327;..."

var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"&#([0-9]*);", 
               x => String.Format("\\u{0:X4}", int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value)));
```

or alternately;

```
var output = String.Join("", WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input)
                   .Select(x => "\\u" + ((int)x).ToString("X4")));
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much this answer is best and also this is exactly what i wanted...
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hindiString.Length * 6);
foreach(char c in hindiString)
  sb.Append(@"\u").Append(((int)c).ToString("X4"));
return sb.ToString()
```

<del>I'm assuming you don't need to worry about anything outside of the BMP. If so you want to merge together UTF-16 high and low surrogates first.</del>
Edit: Scratch that last sentence, js uses UTF-16 internally the same as C#, so the above will work fine outside the BMP too.

However, the corresponding HTML to श्रीगंगानगर। हनुमानगढ़ मार्ग पर लालगढ़ जाटान छावनी के नजदीक शनिवार सुबह सड़क से पन्द्रह is:

```
<p>श्रीगंगानगर। हनुमानगढ़ मार्ग पर लालगढ़ जाटान छावनी के नजदीक शनिवार सुबह सड़क से पन्द्रह</p>
```

And the corresponding javascript is:

```
"श्रीगंगानगर। हनुमानगढ़ मार्ग पर लालगढ़ जाटान छावनी के नजदीक शनिवार सुबह सड़क से पन्द्रह"
```

Or:

```
'श्रीगंगानगर। हनुमानगढ़ मार्ग पर लालगढ़ जाटान छावनी के नजदीक शनिवार सुबह सड़क से पन्द्रह'
```

Why not just use them?

Comment: NP. I just added an optimisation that'll make a difference if the string is large, and you do still need to escape it rather than just use it direct as I suggest.

Comment: Oh wait. Is your staring point in the `&#1234;`format? Sorry, I mis-read that. Do HtmlDecode first then.

Comment: actually i tested it but it didnt work well it is giving me unicode escapes but it is not the exact possible term and i mentioned in my question that i have html code but still thank you for reply and a gr8 answer...
although i hav got wht i wanted from @Joachim Isaksson 's answer

Comment: Yep, that's what my last comment was saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- capture each unicode character using the regular expression `&#([0-9]+);`
- convert the captured part into an integer
- take the hexadecimal representation of the integer in a string
- add `\u` at the beginning and pad the string by `0` from left to make it a 4-character string

Comment: i didnt try it till now as i found the answer but will try it also as it looks good with this explanation... 
n thnks for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in hindi)
{
    sb.Append(@"\u").Append(((int)c).ToString("X4"));
}
return sb.ToString()
```